# Journey Builder with Update Contact Records issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

My SFMC journey (which has successfully validated), looks generally like this:
Steps 1-3 | Step 4 - Update contact record step - set Boolean Field XXX on Data Extension YYY to True | Steps 5-7 | Step 8 - Update contact record step - set Boolean Field XXX on Data Extension YYY to False False) | Exit.

Whenever I set the earlier update contact record step to TRUE, it also sets the latter update contact record step to TRUE.  Whenever I set the latter update contact record step to FALSE, it sets the earlier update contact record to FALSE.  I can't seem to get them to save independently.

I've tried rebuilding from scratch and see the same experience.
I have the data extension YYY set up such that the default value for field XXX is False.
Data Extension YYY is correctly set up in Contact Builder.

Ideas?

Thanks

...............

Here's an image of the relevant portion of the journey.  Whenever I set the Update Contact record on the left to TRUE, the one on the right also becomes TRUE.  Whenever I set the Update contact on the right to FALSE, the one on the left also becomes FALSE.

[image]

Comment: I'm not totally following you. Can you post a screenshot of the journey?

Comment: also not 100% clear, but maybe one thing which you might be overlooking; The contact update activity will update everything in the data extension which catches the contact/subscriber key. That means that if you have two records with the same contact/subscriber key, which go down different paths, then the two records would essentially be updated twice per record.

Comment: That sounds like a bug to me.  You might want to raise a support case to see if it is a known issue.  Since these update activities are independent, they should not both be changing on account of you changing one activity.

Answer (score 1):

Doug is right, update contact activity is design to update data extension where the customer key is the primary key.
If customer key is repeated then they will update with row where they are present.
You have two options:
1º Create a intermediate data extension that is updated by the journey builder and then this data is pull to the main data extension via automation.
2º Depending of the quantity of duplicated rows per customer you can have multiple columns instead of multiple rows to the some customer key. Then each update contact updates one different column.